Error while training pruned and quantized CNN model using TensorFlow Model Optimization
I'm working on a deep learning project where I'm trying to implement a convolutional neural network (CNN) for Human Activity Recognition (HAR) using time-series data. The pipeline involves training a VGG-like teacher model, pruning it for efficiency, applying quantization-aware training, and then distilling the knowledge from the teacher to a smaller student model.
I've structured the pipeline as follows:
Teacher Model: A CNN-based architecture (similar to VGG) that takes windowed time-series data as input for multi-class classification.
Pruning: I use TensorFlow Model Optimization Toolkit (TFMOT) to apply polynomial decay pruning on the teacher model. The pruning works fine initially.
Stripping Pruning Wrappers: After pruning, I strip the pruning wrappers using tfmot.sparsity.keras.strip_pruning().
Quantization-Aware Training (QAT): I apply quantization-aware training to the stripped model using tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model().
Knowledge Distillation: Finally, I create a smaller student model and use the pruned and quantized teacher model’s predictions to train the student via knowledge distillation.
Despite the logical flow of the pipeline, I encounter an error during the pruning and quantization-aware training steps. The issue arises during or after the pruning process, where the pruned model cannot be compiled or trained properly.
The specific error:
The error message I get is
`Error while compiling the pruned model: ValueError: The teacher model must be a Keras Model instance.
RuntimeError: Error while applying pruning to the teacher model: prune_low_magnitude can only prune an object of the following types: keras.models.Sequential, keras functional model, keras.layers.Layer, list of keras.layers.Layer. You passed an object of type: Functional.`
This happens when I attempt to wrap the model in prune_low_magnitude() or quantize_model(). I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm handling the TensorFlow Model Optimization Toolkit, but I can't pinpoint it.
Code Overview:
Model Definition (VGG-like Teacher Model):
def create_vgg_like_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)


#Pruning process
pruning_schedule = tfmot.sparsity.keras.PolynomialDecay(
    initial_sparsity=0.0, final_sparsity=0.5, begin_step=0, end_step=1000
)
pruned_teacher_model = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude(teacher_model, pruning_schedule=pruning_schedule)
pruned_teacher_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


Stripping Pruning Wrappers:
`
stripped_model = tfmot.sparsity.keras.strip_pruning(pruned_teacher_model)
`
Quantization-Aware Training:
quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model
q_aware_teacher_model = quantize_model(stripped_model)
q_aware_teacher_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


Knowledge Distillation Loss:
def knowledge_distillation_loss(y_true, y_pred, teacher_logits, temperature=3):
    soft_labels = tf.nn.softmax(teacher_logits / temperature)
    student_logits = tf.nn.log_softmax(y_pred / temperature)
    distillation_loss = tf.keras.losses.KLDivergence()(soft_labels, student_logits)
    return distillation_loss


Data:
The data is time-series sensor data used for HAR, with windows created for sequences of size 100 and a step size of 50. After windowing, the data is fed into the CNN model.
Window Size: 100
Input Shape: (100, num_features, 1) (where num_features is the number of sensor readings per time step)
Number of Classes: 5 (multi-class classification)
Question:
I’m not sure what’s causing the error regarding the model not being a Keras Model instance. The model works fine until I attempt to apply pruning or quantization. I’d appreciate any guidance on:
What might be going wrong with the pruning and quantization setup?
How to correctly wrap the model for pruning and quantization?
Any debugging tips or potential issues I might be overlooking?
Thanks in advance for any help!
